# NestJS - how to check if JWT can access specific endpoint

Tags: node.js, jwt, nestjs

Let's say I have 3 endpoints: A is for generating JWT token, B for accessing data of user X and C for accessing data of user Y. Now, what I want to do is, that I can from recieved token somehow in controller guards figure out, if user can access endpoint.

So, token generated for user X can only access endpoint B, token generated for user Y can only access endpoint C.

Token has to be generated at endpoint A, since users sign in at same form.
If question is unclear ask in comment.

Comment: what is the question? Like are you trying to let an authenticated user access specific endpoint or are you looking at specific quality of that user to determine if they are authorize to access the route.

Comment: @HenryLy Depending on type of account, I want user to access only specific endpoints.

Comment: How do you add the account to the JWT, if you do at all. Or is the JWT just consistent of the user id? How do you have it in your rules that certain accounts should or should not activate certain routes?

Comment: Add a role on the JWT payload, then use the decorator @SetMetadata() to assign roles on each endpoint and you can check on your guard with a Reflector if the user is allowed to access that endpoint.

Comment: @JuanRambal This worked, SetMetadata turned out to be the cleanest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can do that by specifying in the payload a role, by this role you set a guard on each endpoint which role has the access to it. let me give an example:

I believe that you have a function where you fill you **payload** kind of this function :

```
    createJwtPayload(user){
    let data: JwtPayload = {
        userData: user,
        companyId : user.company.id,
        role:user.role.name, // for us this where we specify the role for our User
    };

   ......
}
```

Now We have to create guards we need to specify access for x endpoints
let start with **Admin Guard:**

```
    @Injectable()
            export class AdminGuard implements CanActivate {
        async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
         const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
   
      if (!request.headers.authorization) {
        return false;
      }
      request.user = await this.validateToken(request.headers.authorization);
       if( request.user.role == ROLES.SUPER_ADMIN) {
          return true;
        }
       return false;
             }

         async validateToken(auth: string) {
            ......
      }
```

lets make the second guard we call it **EmployeGuard** :

```
 ....
@Injectable()
export class EmployeGuard implements CanActivate {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
   
      if (!request.headers.authorization) {
        return false;
      }
      request.user = await this.validateToken(request.headers.authorization);
         if( request.user.role == ROLES.COMPANY_ADMIN ||  request.user.role == ROLES.USER) {
          return true;
        }
       return false;
  }

  async validateToken(auth: string) {
    ......
}
```

Now to use these guards we just need to use  @UseGuards() in our endpoint :

```
      @Post()
    @UseGuards(AdminGuard)
    async addCompany(@Res() res, @Body() createDto: CompanyDto) {
      ........
    }

   @Get(':companyID')
    @UseGuards(EmployeGuard)
    async getcompany(@Res() res, @Param('companyID') companyID) {
       ....
     }
```

**Bonus*: you can @useGuards on the controller to make sure the all endpoints use it*

Comment: Used this with SetMetadata solution from Juan, thanks!